# SMS receive notify

Tags: android

I'm writing an Android app (**API level 15** sorry I cannot get over this for compatibily reasons) that should received an SMS and show a toast / popup. 
This app will have standard activities for settings and/or logging but incoming SMS should be *received* also when in background.

Googling around I found several pieces of codes that should work as I need for but unluckly it does not.

These are the entries I added in my manifest file:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    [...]

    <receiver android:name="com.bananainc.smsmirror.SMSListener">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

and this's my `SMSListener` class:

```
public class SMSListener extends BroadcastReceiver
{
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
 {
    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))
    {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

        if (bundle != null)
            try {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

                for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    String from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    String body = msgs[i].getMessageBody();

                    Toast.makeText(context, "SMS" +  from + " : " + body , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Log.d("EVENT", "SMS" +  from + " : " + body);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception caught", e.getMessage());
            }
    }
 }
}
```

of course I got also code for managing `MainActiity` but, up to now, this's not involved in incoming SMS management.

Where did I fail?

Please note that `SMSListener` code seems not to run. If I try to debug its thread stay 'suspended' as it is never triggered. As a matter of fact no log lines are dumped in `logcat`.

I noticed that in logcat i got this warning:

```
07-05 17:05:35.293 8277-8277/com.bananainc.smsmirror W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
```

Maybe is important.

BTW I'm running `Android Studio 2.1.2` under Windows 10 Home 64 bits.

Comment: register broadcast receiver in mainactivity

Comment: @Shanto thnx... you mean just to move the `<receiver>...</receiver>` entry inside `MainActivity` one or to define the handler by code as an internal member of `MainActivity` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this permission also to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

If you are using android-M, just write below lines in your activity where you want want sms toast.

```
 final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 1;


final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS))
        permissionsNeeded.add("Receive SMS");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS))
        permissionsNeeded.add("Read SMS");

    if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
        if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
            String message = "You need to grant access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);
            showMessageOKCancel(message, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]), MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                    }
                }
            });
            return;
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]), MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
        return;
    }

private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionsList.add(permission);
            if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(OtpActivity.this).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK", okListener).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null).create().show();
}



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
            Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
            if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
            } else {
            }
        }
        break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version phone are you using?Marshmallow?

Comment: yep. I'm using Marshmallow but I have to compiile for API 15 and above.

Comment: So in Marshmallow, you need to give run-time permissions for using read sms or receive sms permissions.

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer even if it's not fully correct but it just gave me the correct hint. thnx.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to application permission but did not require all the code from Drv (sorry). 
In my inexperience I tought the app installed trough ADB should have all the required permissions set by default (of course this's not correct for security reasons etc). Setting rights trough application manager fixed the issue.
Thanks anyone.